# Ubuntu 22.04 Chrome broswer can't see any text or image content after update

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome

Yesterday (25-05-2023) I got an update, and after that update I can't see any text or image content in Chrome browser. Even in the developer tools window. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFXd4.png)
[image]

Comment: Read this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469276/chrome-not-loading-pages-properly/1469287#1469287

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1442633

Answer (score 16):

remove cache from ~/.config/google-chrome/Default$ rm -rf GPUCache/

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: I just had the same issue with the latest updates at 22.04.2 LTS, and this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Disable hardware acceleration in Chrome

- Open Chrome.
- Click the horizontal ellipsis menu button in the top-right corner and click on Settings.
- Click on System.
- Under the “System” section, turn off the “Use hardware acceleration when available” toggle switch.
- Click the Relaunch button.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot? So I know where to click, because I can't see nothing, no words or icons, in the page chrome://settings/system

Answer (score 3):

Go to  Settings -> click System -> and turn off *Use hardware acceleration when available* as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: its worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I tried deleting all the gpu/shader cache but it didn't work for me. Then, just disabled hardware acceleration option and the pages started to show normally.