# Why does the latest set of video drivers break Chromium browsers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, chromium, browser, gpu-driver

The following update caused the Chromium browser to fail:

```
Start-Date: 2023-05-23  18:59:16
Commandline: apt-get upgrade libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa 
libglx-mesa0 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-driver
s
Requested-By: userx (1200)
Upgrade: libglx-mesa0:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.
2), libgbm1:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2), libxat
racker2:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2), mesa-va-dr
ivers:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2), libgl1-mesa-
dri:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2), mesa-vulkan-dr
ivers:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2), libglapi-mes
a:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2), libegl-mesa0:amd
64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2), mesa-vdpau-drivers:am
d64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1, 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.2)
End-Date: 2023-05-23  18:59:17
```

To work around I had to toggle off the hardware accel (GPU) to get Chromium to render the settings page, then toggle off the browser setting for the GPU.

`$ google-chrome --disable-gpu`

Then visit:

`chrome://settings/system`

Disable hardware acceleration and exit, restart as you normally would.

But why give up the hardware GPU for rendering, what has changed?

The begin of the error output from Chrome is:

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[39080:39080:0528/160509.023513:ERROR:shared_context_state.cc(77)] Skia shader compilation error
```

---

```
// Vertex SKSL
#extension GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation: require
uniform float4 sk_RTAdjust;uniform float3x3 umatrix_S1_c0;in float2 position;in half4 color;in float2 localCoord;flat out half4 vcolor_S0;noperspective out float2 vTransformedCoords_3_S0;void main() {// Primitive Processor QuadPerEdgeAAGeometryProcessor
vcolor_S0 = color;sk_Position = position.xy01;{
vTransformedCoords_3_S0 = float3x2(umatrix_S1_c0) * localCoord.xy1;
}
}
```

Other Info:

```
$ dmesg -T | grep Pavilion

DMI: HP HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eg2xxx/89F7, BIOS F.07 08/10/2022

$ lspci | grep NVIDIA

Graphics GPU : 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce MX550] (rev a1)

$ uname -a
Linux Machine 6.1.7 #2 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jan 18 09:26:45 MST 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

All worked well prior to this update.

As another user posted as a reply, this post seems to address it.

[Since 23 May 2023 Ubuntu 22.04 Mesa updates, Chrome won't display website graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469116/since-23-may-2023-ubuntu-22-04-mesa-updates-chrome-wont-display-website-graphi)

FireFox was NOT affected for me as they offered.

Removing the cache resolves this until the next update is the claim:

rm ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache/*

rm ~/.config/opera/GPUCache/*

That fixed BOTH Opera and Google Chrome.

Comment: Check this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469116/since-23-may-2023-ubuntu-22-04-mesa-updates-chrome-wont-display-website-graphi

Comment: Thanks for that, this helps, I was not able to locate that post.  I added it to my OP and included some other results for Opera.

Comment: 非常感谢，这两种都是可以正常解决的
 - 解决1：google-chrome --disable-gpu
 - 解决2：rm ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/GPUCache/*

应该是 2023-05-26 升级系统导致，这个版本的chrome是很早前安装的，结合chrome命令行启动错误：GLSL,怀疑是升级的：libglx-mesa0 导致

Comment: You are welcome.  Thanks for your reply.  This summarizes what can be done to use the Chromium browsers with GPU hardware calls enabled, the command line switches help since you can invoke the browser to change settings and have the pages rendered correctly. Stormlord pointed me to the other posting that detailed much of the problem. I confirm FireFox works for me, and this fails on my system for both Opera and Chrome.